# Include bootstrap code in two different chunks

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I'm struggling a bit with web pack for a particular use case and I was wondering whether somebody already faced this problem.

So:

I have 3 entries:

```
application: 'src/app.js'
seedFile: 'src/seed.js'
vendor: ['jquery', 'axios', 'otherLibs']
```

And then I'm using the `CommonChunksPlugin` for the vendor entry

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin
  name: 'vendor'
  minChunks: Infinity
```

The plugin will remove all the references to selected libraries and bundle them just once in the common chunk.

The webpack runtime/bootstrap code gets bundled into `vendor.js` file as well, which means I have to include two files in my application in order to make it work:

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="application.js"></script>
```

And that is totally ok.

Now what I would like to do (which is where I'm struggling) is that the `seed` entry would be "self-contained", which means I can use it without having to serve the `vendor.js` file in order to get the runtime/bootstrap code instantiated.

*Note:* the `seed` entry does **NOT** contain any dependency to any `vendor` library. The only reason to include that file is simply to have the web pack bootstrap/runtime code.

Do you guys know what would be the best way to handle this scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: I have opened a [feature request on github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4470). Hopefully somebody from webpack team might consider the idea of implementing this or give us directions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if that what you want to achieve, but you can do the following:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
  names: ['commons', 'vendor', 'manifest'],
  minChuncks: Infinity
})
```

Where in `commons.js` you will have all common code for all of your entries (it may be empty for your particular case). And in `manifest.js` file you will have only the `webpack` bootstrap code.

Comment: I know that, but unfortunately that would still need me to include 2 files - I would like to make sure that just that particular webpack entry would be self-sustainable.

Comment: hm, may be use `gulp` after webpack finishes bundling to concatenate those files?

Comment: I wanted to avoid that but it seems like yeah, webpack is not to run that scenario by itself.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this scenario is not supported by Webpack natively. However, it's possible to export an array of configurations which you can model according to your needs.